# Is Bisecting K-Means of Apache Spark deterministic?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cluster-analysis

Does anyone know if the bisecting K-Means algorithm of Apache Spark is deterministic? I thought it is but in my implementation it gives me different results every time. Any ideas?

```
BisectingKMeans bkm = new BisectingKMeans().setK(initialval);
BisectingKMeansModel model = bkm.fit(df);
Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(df);
```